# How to make a fixed position navbar with equal spacing?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I already found out that display and position cannot both be used at the same time, but can't seem to find another solution. My code right now shows the navbar how I want it but I can't find a way to fix the position so it stays when scrolling. Thanks!

```css
.navbar {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: justify;
  border: dotted blue;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.navbar:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  /* Ensures there are at least 2 lines of text, so justification works */
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a id="home" href="#home">home</a>
  <a id="projects" href="#projects">projects</a>
  <a id="shop" href="#shop">shop</a>
  <a id="about" href="#about">about</a>
  <a id="contact" href="#contact">contact</a>
</div>
```

tried out before and after elements and also to put the whole thing in another div but can't make it work

Edit: have another quick question: is there a quick fix to change the fact that I can highlight the long space between the navigation links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the position of your `.navbar` when scrolling, you can use `position: fixed;` and `right: 0;`

```css
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: justify;
    border: dotted blue;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

Comment: thanks, way easier than expected :) is there a quick fix to change the fact that I can highlight the long space between the navigation links?

Comment: You want to highlight the long space between the navigation links? Can you explain what you want to do in a better way?

Comment: Hope I can explain this well enough. I am currently able to highlight the space between the navigation links just like you can highlight the [space] between these : home                      projects                         ... I want to fix that so there's nothing to highlight there. (my cursor also changes to the "text" cursor when moving over the space between the navbar links.

Answer (score 3):

```css
.navbar { 
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  height: 50px; 

  display: flex; 
  justify-content: space-between; 
  align-items: center; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply this CSS rule:

```css
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: justify;
  border: dotted blue;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```